# Simple matrix question

Tags: linear-algebra

$x$ is an $(n*1)$ vector
$A$ is an $(n*n)$ matrix
$B$ is an $(n*k)$ matrix
$u$ is an $(k*1)$ vector
$P$ is a positive semi-definite symmetric matrix
$E$ means mathematical expectation

$E(x'A'PBu+u'B'PAx)=2x'A'PBu$

How does this equation hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second term in the sum is the transpose of the first term.
The first term is a scalar. So the second term is the same scalar.